# ArcGIS Online map labels do not appear in ArcGIS app for Android?

Tags: android, arcgis-online, arcgis-android

I have a map on ArcGIS online.  The map shows labels just fine as you can see on my web map (http://bit.ly/1q7hc0h).

The problem is that when I view the map on may Android device using the ArcGIS app the labels do not appear.

I have the most recent version of the Android app and I do not have scale dependent labels set in ArcGIS Online.

Any ideas on why the labels are not showing in the mobile version?

Answer (score 1):

AGOL labels are not supported on mobile, e.g. Collector.
https://geonet.esri.com/message/392275?sr=search&searchId=6f4adad4-6432-41e9-9877-d41c67d943b9&searchIndex=1#392275

Comment: Would you be able to expand your answer with more information to support this assertion, please?  About a paragraph is the minimum length that prevents your answers being flagged up as being of low quality.

Answer (score 1):

download the data in collector as offline ( on device) then you will see label. ensure to prepare label in webmap. Not sure if it has start to support online as yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sadly displaying labels on android doesn't work. However, when using my iPad Pro using the same app it shows the labels just fine.  You may need an iOS device to display the information.